# Node.js string inside javascript object argument

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm not really sure how to name this problem but essentially I am using the Mongoose package for MongoDB and the function is not behaving. The function in question is:

```
var value = 'onetwothree'
model.findOne({ 'name': value }, callback)
```

which allows me to search the database for the attribute `'name'`. However, if I try to pass `'name'` in as a variable, the function doesn't work. For example, this doesn't work:

```
var attribute = 'name'
model.findOne({ attribute: value}, callback)
```

How do I call the `findOne()` function while making the attribute argument variable, i.e. I could pass in `'name'`, `'age'`, `'city'`, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just create the object before passing it into the function and assign the dynamic property using the `[]` notation:

```
var query = {};
var attr = 'city';
var val = 'Miami';

// set the dynamic property
query[attr] = val; // { city: 'Miami' }

model.findOne(query, callback)
```

Or in ES6 (if you're using Babel) you can do it directly with a Computed Property Name:

```
const attr = 'city';
const val = 'Miami';
const query = { [attr]: val }; // { city: 'Miami' }

model.findOne(query, callback);
```

Comment: glad to help mate :)